# Windows Store app. UserControl

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an assembly that has a blank usercontrol say TestControl.

When I reference this control from a Page in the application, the XAML designer produces this error.

```
XAML parsing failed.
```

The Assembly with the control is referenced, the namespace is included

```
xmlns:controls="using:Tfl.TestControl"
```

The designer intellisense recognises the control.

```
<controls:TestControl></controls:TestControl>
```

The application builds succesfully, but won't run.

So, for Windows Store apps, is there some magic required for including UserControls from external assemblies?

Comment: shouldn't your namespace be "using:Tfl" if your control is TestControl - if so, this shouldn't even build.  Or is your namespace really Tfl.TestControl enclosing a class also named TestControl?

Comment: Can you drill down to see if there are any more details in the exception?